# Make built-in lru_cache skip caching when function returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, lru

Here's a simplified function for which I'm trying to add a `lru_cache` for -

```
from functools import lru_cache, wraps

@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def validate_token(token):
    if token % 3:
        return None
    return True

for x in range(1000):
    validate_token(x)

print(validate_token.cache_info())
```

outputs -

```
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1000, maxsize=1000, currsize=1000)
```

As we can see, it would also cache `args` and `returned` values for the `None` returns as well. In above example, I want the `cache_size` to be 334, where we are returning non-None values. In my case, my function having large no. of `args` might return a different value if previous value was `None`. **So I want to avoid caching the `None` values**.

I want to avoid reinventing the wheel and implementing a `lru_cache` again from scratch. Is there any good way to do this?

Here are some of my attempts -

**1. Trying to implement own cache (which is non-lru here) -**

```
from functools import wraps 

# global cache object
MY_CACHE = {}

def get_func_hash(func):
    # generates unique key for a function. TODO: fix what if function gets redefined?
    return func.__module__ + '|' + func.__name__

def my_lru_cache(func):
    name = get_func_hash(func)
    if not name in MY_CACHE:
        MY_CACHE[name] = {}
    @wraps(func)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if tuple(args) in MY_CACHE[name]:
            return MY_CACHE[name][tuple(args)]
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if value is not None:
            MY_CACHE[name][tuple(args)] = value
        return value
    return function_wrapper

@my_lru_cache
def validate_token(token):
    if token % 3:
        return None
    return True

for x in range(1000):
    validate_token(x)

print(get_func_hash(validate_token))
print(len(MY_CACHE[get_func_hash(validate_token)]))
```

outputs -

```
__main__|validate_token
334
```

**2. I realised that the `lru_cache` doesn't do caching when an `exception` is raised within the wrapped function -**

```
from functools import wraps, lru_cache

def my_lru_cache(func):
    @wraps(func)
    @lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if value is None:
            # TODO: change this to a custom exception
            raise KeyError
        return value
    return function_wrapper

def handle_exception(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        except KeyError:
            return None
    return function_wrapper    

@handle_exception
@my_lru_cache
def validate_token(token):
    if token % 3:
        return None
    return True

for x in range(1000):
    validate_token(x)

print(validate_token.__wrapped__.cache_info())
```

outputs -

```
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=334, maxsize=1000, currsize=334)
```

Above correctly caches only the `334` values, but needs wrapping the function twice and accessing the `cache_info` in a weird manner `func.__wrapped__.cache_info()`.

How do I better achieve the behaviour of not caching when `None`(or specific) values are returned using built-in `lru_cache` decorator in a pythonic way?

Comment: This is surprising to me that cachetools doesn't have a basic way to not-cache None values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the two lines marked here:

```py
def handle_exception(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return value
        except KeyError:
            return None

    function_wrapper.cache_info = func.cache_info    # Add this
    function_wrapper.cache_clear = func.cache_clear  # Add this
    return function_wrapper
```

You can do both wrappers in one function:

```py
def my_lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False):
    class CustomException(Exception):
        pass

    def decorator(func):
        @lru_cache(maxsize=maxsize, typed=typed)
        def raise_exception_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if value is None:
                raise CustomException
            return value

        @wraps(func)
        def handle_exception_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return raise_exception_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
            except CustomException:
                return None

        handle_exception_wrapper.cache_info = raise_exception_wrapper.cache_info
        handle_exception_wrapper.cache_clear = raise_exception_wrapper.cache_clear
        return handle_exception_wrapper

    if callable(maxsize):
        user_function, maxsize = maxsize, 128
        return decorator(user_function)

    return decorator
```

Answer (score 6):

Use exceptions to prevent caching:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fname(x):
    print('worked')

    raise Exception('')

    return 1


for _ in range(10):
    try:
        fname(1)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

In example above "worked" will be printed 10 times.